# Clearing Disk Space at Command Line to fix Low Graphics Mode Problem

Tags: disk-usage, delete

My SSD is completely full and I can't access the desktop to be able to delete these files. I need help on how to set the command to delete the files of a particular folder ie Videos

Answer (score 2):

To drop to text console press:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

To be efficient with searching for the biggest files in your home folder:

`du ~ | sort -n -r| less`

or just in the folder *Video*

`du ~/Video | sort -n -r| less`

Answer (score 1):

the commands you need are...

To see which folder you're in:

```
pwd
```

To change directory (folder)":

```
cd /home/u29/Videos      (for example)
```

List the files there by size:

```
ls -lS
```

Then, if file "vid887.mp4: is the last on the list, then delete it with:

```
rm vid887.mp4
```

To see how much disk space you have free:

```
df -h
```